# C# ASP.NET over-rule non enforcable business rules

Tags: .net, validation, business-rules

I am trying to figure out the best generic way to handle business rules where the rule is not always enforceable.
The form is being submitted to the database via a stored_procedure call.  Currently the business logic is written into the stored_procedure rather than a separate Business Application Layer.  The stored procedures return a data set with the errors and error levels (info, advice, warning, error and fatal)

Info is just to give an update on something which may be required.
Advice allows the user to abort the update/insert but the default action is to continue
Warning allows the user to abort the update/insert but the default action is to cancel
Error violates a mandatory business rule, normally relating to data integrity and will force the update/insert to be cancelled but the user can choose to modify the data being submitted and try again
Fatal is something that the user cannot fix (lost connection to the database, user permissions revoked, data changed since form was populated etc..)and will force the transaction to be aborted

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

A form for setting up season codes

- Code
- Descrption
- StartDate
- EndDate

There are two types of validation required:

Mandatory: E.g. Code and description must be completed and must be unique, Start date must be before End date

Optional: Start and end dates will normally be contigious, i.e. the start date of the next season will be the day after the end date of the previoius season, however this is not ALWAYS the case.  I want to warn the user that they have POTENTIALLY made an error and have them confirm that the entered data is correct.  If they do confirm then I need to ignore the validation rule on re-submission.

I am thinking that an extra parameter in the stored procedure to ignore Optional (info and warning) which is only set on the re-submission if the user has confirmed the issues as being OK. Error and Fatal will still cause the update to fail.

Can anyone propose a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a execution type business rule, the one that invokes a method (rule action) if the rule evaluates to True. The action can take parameters (for instance, an enum ErrorLevel) and act accordingly, logging errors, notifying the user, saving user's entry, etc, etc). Something like:

```
If UserRole is Admin and (StartDate is less than or equal to EndDate)
then Prosess(ErrorLevel.Info)
else Abort(ErrorLevel.Fatal)
```